# Notification LargeIcon with text and round background

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm trying to create a bitmap to put in a notification's LargeIcon, I set the text but I can't get to set a rounded background color.

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, int textColor) {
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setColor(textColor);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    float baseline = -paint.ascent(); // ascent() is negative
    int width = (int) (paint.measureText(text) + 0.5f); // round
    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 0.5f);
    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, baseline, paint);
    return image;
}
```

A diffrent aproach to the same result is welcome